# Include the same sidebar on every .html page

Tags: css, html

I am learning to program in HTML. I have multiple pages on my dummy website, all of them with the same sidebar. Now, the sidebar is *hard-coded* into each file; that means that if a small change has to occur, I have to change every file manually.

I believe this is not the best practice, but is there a better way to do it without using PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: "without using PHP or JavaScript?" -- no way, really. without server-side programming or Javascript, your HTML files can share parts of the pages only through IFRAME.  Old-style web pages used to have IFRAMEs.

Comment: You can create your own HTML renderer which will run over your rules and create "dynamic" HTML out of your templates.

Comment: Probably the thing, what you looking for is [HTML imports](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) from WebComponents.But according to [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports) only Chrone and Opera support this feature for now.

Comment: If you are using Apache, try [server-side includes](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy your sidebar HTML code to sidebar.php and include it with PHP include or require command:

```
require("sidebar.php");
```

Read more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Answer (score -1):

How about an `<iframe>` this is the only way I can think of using just HTML